Prevent Automatic Mounting and Detection of M.2 Disks in Ubuntu
I currently have two M.2 disks in my system: one with Windows installed and the other used for storage. I would like to install Ubuntu on a third SATA disk. From what I understand, the correct way to install Ubuntu is to disconnect the other two M.2 disks during installation, which I can do without any issues.
However, my goal is to ensure that once I reconnect the M.2 disks and boot into Linux from the boot menu, the system does NOT automatically mount or detect them, and I don’t want them to be visible to Linux at all. Essentially, I want Linux to "ignore" these disks entirely.
Could anyone guide me on how to achieve this configuration in Ubuntu? I’m looking for a way to make sure that these disks are not accessible or mounted when I boot into Ubuntu.
Thanks in advance for your help!

I would not say disconnecting them is "correct" but it is certainly safer.  Note that linux and windows should share an EFI partition, so if the efi partition is on one of those, disconnecting it is not best.

@user10489 I don’t want a dual boot setup. I prefer having two separate operating systems installed on two different disks. The idea is to manually choose which system to boot by pressing F8 during startup

In that case, it's probably irrelevant if you share an EFI partition or not, but you still can.

Many new systems have an UEFI setting to disable internal SSD or NVMe drives. Then you do not have to physically remove them. You will want gpt partitioning with an ESP - efi system partition on new drive. While it may seem backwards to prevent Linux from seeing NTFS partitions used to be to actually create mount point & add to fstab with parameters preventing auto mounting. With Windows using bitlocker and fast startup that may not even work unless you also have setting to bypass fstab entry if not found. You can also set udev rules. man udev
